# base64decode a file encoded with unix base64

Tags: powershell, base64

I'm not into powershell coding (prefer python ed.).
Although I need a script to change a base64 file created on unix back to binairy:

```
echo notepad.exe | base64 > exe.b64
```

I've managed to write some code today on the fly that stripped the '\r\n' from the end but I couldn't get te result to file. It would always print integers to file instead of binary. Likely some of the experienced admins here can do this in a oneliner.

I'm looking for somthing that would run as:

```
b64_2bin.ps exe.b43 notepad.exe
```

and give me back the original notepad.exe

===
Anser 1 seems correct:

I dragged the notepad.exe from a windows VMWare guest to my Linux desktop.
There I ran:

```
cat notepad.exe | base64 > notepad.b64


head notepad.b64 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```

I drag notepad.b64 back to the windows 7 desktop and run the command:

```
[System.Convert]::FromBase64String((Get-Content .\notepad.b64)) | Set-Content -Encoding Byte .\notepad2.exe
```

and that just works. thanks! md5 sum same as original file!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for us to answer when you don't provide the script that encoded it and what you have tried. Show some effort. That's said, does this work?

```
[System.Convert]::FromBase64String((Get-Content c:\exe.b43)) | Set-Content -Encoding Byte c:\notepad.exe
```

Comment: Another a [nice example](http://www.getautomationmachine.com/en/blog/item/embedding-files-in-powershell-scripts) shows how to embed DLL in Powershell script.